# How can I display a text field with an ellipsis into a flexbox that shrinks to fit?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ellipsis

I am looking for a flexbox solution to a problem that I have seen partial but not complete solutions. I have a field that can have a lot of text, so I want to show an ellipsis if it gets beyond a certain size. However it can also be quite short, and so in those cases I want the field to the right of it to next to it. I can do one or the other, but can't figure out how to do both.

Here's an example which shows how to use `minWidth` to get the ellipsis to show:

https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zqedEr

Note that there are 3 examples; it is example #3 with class `.long-and-truncated-with-child-corrected` which needs to be updated to resolve this issue.

It is works great when the screen shrinks:
[image]

But when it grows, there is too much space to the right of the text:
[image]

In this example, I would like the green dots to be immediately to the right of the "thank you" text. Thank you.

Comment: you want this https://jsfiddle.net/zbL3ouj6/?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Curiously, it only works for me in my real page if I add a max-width like I've done here: https://jsfiddle.net/shawnlauzon/ejyxq1vz/28/ -- any idea why that would be?

Comment: can you show me your real page? you have probably more CSS involved

Comment: Oh yeah, there's a lot more CSS involved :) It's not public yet, but hopefully soon. I'll share it when I can, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove flex grow in .long-and-truncated

```
.long-and-truncated {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

If you want space after the text, add column-gap on .flex-parent

```
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
```

Edit:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the long-and-truncated class is one that doesn't solve the ellipsis problem. It was clear with the original text, but that was lost when I just have the codepen. It's the .long-and-truncated-with-child-corrected class which is closest to working. I'll update the issue.

Comment: You want the 3 examples to solve the ellipsis problem?

Comment: @ShawnLauzon look at my edit isn't that what you want?

Comment: No, I want example 3 to do both: to show ellipses when the box is small, but at all times have the green squares just to the right of the text.

Comment: Example 1 in my screenshot show ellipses when shrinked and if not the green squares are attached right next to it. I'm not exactly sure what you want

Comment: Example 1 is a special case that only works if the text is directly in the flexbox. So it's example 3 which I need a solution for. The original problem is solved here: https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/